# select sum hours in linq

Tags: c#, linq, timespan

It will be hard to explain but I'll try
I've got a table with some fields, and that table got subtable with rows (I'm not talking about SQL, its DB4O, but I use linq). Rows got `timefrom` and `timeto`, example:

```
maintable:
Description,
CreateDate,
....
mainTableRows:
08:00,
09:00,
some description
```

Now I need to make a query that will sum hours from rows, like this:

```
09:00-08:00 = 1hour(first row) + 10:00-09:00 (second row)
```

and so on.

Something like:

```
var item = from mainTable m 
           select new
             { 
               m.Id, 
               Hours = m.Rows.Sum(c=> new { Hour = c.TimeTo - c.TimeFrom }) 
             }
```

Thanks all for help, this is mine full solution:

```
var item = from mainTable m 
               select new
                 { 
                   m.Id, 
                   Hours = String.Format("{0:HH:mm}", (new DateTime((p.TimesheetRows.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (subtotal, t) => subtotal += (t.TimeTo - t.TimeFrom)).Ticks))))
                 }
```

Comment: Whole only?  Or do you want fractions of hours?  Also is Rows a `DataTable`, or some sort of `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: What's the actual question here? You provide a sample query, but you don't say where it fails?

Comment: well... there is a question ive asked how to achive mine problem this query was only an example, because it doesnt work like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the total elapsed time, you can do:

```
 var item = from mainTable m 
       select new
         { 
           m.Id, 
           Hours = m.Rows
                    .Select(c => c.TimeTo - c.TimeFrom)
                    .Aggregate( (working, next) => working.Add(next) )
                    .TotalHours
         }
```

Comment: +1 Best solution, because you can round to full hours later on, without intermediate rounding erros, or take the detailed timespan as it is.

Comment: @Philip: That was my thought - but it's not completely clear what the OP wants...

Comment: The sample is missing the lambda: `.Aggregate( (working, next) => working.Add(next) )`

Comment: @Metro: Thanks - typed it out too fast.  Fixed

Comment: thanks, but ive made it before u posted ;) here is mine full solution: `Hours = String.Format("{0:HH:mm}", (new DateTime((p.TimesheetRows.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (subtotal, t) => subtotal += (t.TimeTo - t.TimeFrom)).Ticks))))`  ive added some more things because i needed only to get HH:MM also i needed to take time diff before sum

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you are pretty near. Only the aggregation could be made after the selection.

```
private class TestData 
{
    public DateTime from;
    public DateTime to;
}

public static test()
{
   Collection<TestData> x = new Collection<TestData>();
   x.Select(item => (item.to - item.from).Hours).Sum();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Rows is some sort of `IEnumerable<T>`, you can do this if you want fractions of hours too:

```
var item = from mainTable m 
           select new
             { 
               m.Id, 
               Hours = m.Row.Sum(c => (c.TimeTo - c.TimeFrom).TotalHours) 
             }
```

Or this if you want the sum of whole-number hours:

```
var item = from mainTable m 
           select new
             { 
               m.Id, 
               Hours = m.Row.Sum(c => (c.TimeTo - c.TimeFrom).Hours)                 
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

`(c.TimeTo - c.TimeFrom)` is of type TimeSpan:

```
var item = from m in mainTable 
           select new { m.Id, Hours = m.Rows.Sum(c => (c.TimeTo - c.TimeFrom).TotalHours)};
```